# filter data inside a file

Tags: grep, awk, regex

I have a file that contains this type of data.

Input:

```
mstage1.service-ft.google.com:mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com:mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.serviceint.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com:mstage1.service-int.google.com
```

But I want to remove colon and after colon next subdomain should be in a new line like.

Output:

```
mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.serviceint.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
```

Thanks if you could help me with that, I am new to these kinds of stuff

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please [edit] your answer and tell us what you've tried already.

Comment: I am new to these all things  sorry I know I should learn some grep regex and awk but Its hard to do when you have low span of time

Comment: `awk` is indeed the way to go. I don't mind helping people when they're stuck, *but I do mind doing all their work for them.* **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: that's okay, my bad!

Comment: But someone else doesn't mind1  **;-)** (anser upvoted!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you want to replace `:` with cariage return, simply use the stream editor `sed`:

```
sed  's|:|\n|g' /input/file.txt
```

Learn more about `sed` : https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-sed
With the given sample data :

```
user@host:~/Test$ cat ./input/file.txt 
mstage1.service-ft.google.com:mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com:mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.serviceint.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com:mstage1.service-int.google.com
user@host:~/Test$ 
user@host:~/Test$ sed  's|:|\n|g' ./input/file.txt 
mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.serviceint.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
```

But if you want to keep first column (ie remove what is after `:`) then use `cut`

```
user@host:~/Test$ cut -d ":" -f 1 ./input/file.txt 
mstage1.service-ft.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
mstage1.serviceint.google.com
mstage1.service-int.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks that's worked :)